# Kuberenetes Deployment Controller - Multilpe Vs Single?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment specification that says launch 3 pods with nginx containers... Kubernetes creates an deployment object (spec + status). I learnt that deployment controller keeps track of this object and brings status to a desired state of 3 pods ... but couldn't find whether we get one deployment controller created for each deployment object or is there one deployment controller that monitors all deployment object ? Same applies to replication controller too? I know answering one would answer the other one...

Answer (score 2):

Deployment controller internally uses replication controller which creates replicaset. Deployment controller and replication controller are part of kubernetes [controller manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-controller-manager) . You generally have more than one controller manager in a cluster for high availability. So for example if you have 3 controller managers then there are 3 deployment and replication controller internally. But at a time one of the controller manager is selected as leader and is active. So even though there are 3 deployment controller and 3 replication controller only one of those are active at a time.

Comment: Thank you Arghya. I got answer to my question...  basically I was trying to know if there will be an instance of a deployment manager created for each deployment manifest in a cluster......  For ex. if there are 5 deployments ( just assume ) will there be 5 deployment managers created.. but from the response you gave, I understood it is not and I get what you are saying.  .....Thank you so much for responding.